# Linux equivalent header for synch.h 

Tags: linux, shared-libraries, header-files

I have a C code which contains `#include<synch.h>` The code compiles successfully in solaris but in Linux I find that the header is missing. 
As suggested in a few links, can `"sync.h"` be used instead?
Or is there any other equivalent header for synch.h in Linux?

Comment: It would useful to know what sync.h does for you .. is it part of a another project? Is it an OS header?

Comment: Hi Spaceghost, it is an OS header.

Comment: What does that provide? It is hard to identify if there is an equivalent based on name alone.

Answer (score 4):

The synch.h header in Solaris is for Solaris threads.  Among other things, it provides declarations for semaphores and mutexes.  You can either this library (http://sctl.sourceforge.net/sctl_v1.1_rn.html) to give you Solaris compatible threading on Linux or, a much better idea, rework your code to use POSIX threading.

Comment: Added '#include <pthread.h>' and removed '#include <synch.h>'

Comment: May get "undefined reference to symbol 'pthread_create@@GLIBC_XXX", solve by including '-lpthread' as a compiler flag. --> 
 https://stackoverflow.com/q/34143265/8960744

Answer (score 1):

We can't be sure, but one likely possibility is that this is the `synch.h` that's part of [NACHOS,](http://www.cs.washington.edu/homes/tom/nachos/) which is often used in educational environments. Head over to the NACHOS project page and read up on it, and decide whether you think that's probably the right thing; if so, you can download and install it for free.